# How to efficiently change numpy array elements depending on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.6

I have a 3 dimensional `uint8` numpy array. I want to increase all the elements by 1 which has these values: 0,1,3,16,17,18. And set others to 0. I have tried using traditional for loops which is really really slow.

Tried using python indexing techniques to set other values to 255 (which will later be changed to 0)

```
mask[(mask[:,:,:] != 0) & (mask[:,:,:] != 1) & (mask[:,:,:] != 3) & (mask[:,:,:] != 16) & (mask[:,:,:] != 17) & (mask[:,:,:] != 18)] = 255
```

Then increasing the values by 1

```
mask[(mask[:,:,:] == 0) & (mask[:,:,:] == 1) & (mask[:,:,:] == 3) & (mask[:,:,:] == 16) & (mask[:,:,:] == 17) & (mask[:,:,:] == 18)] = mask[:,:,:]+1 #gives me error
```

Then changing the 255 to 0

```
mask[mask[:,:,:] == 255] = 0
```

The middle operation gives me error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

How to do that efficiently. Preferably in one go. Not 3 times iterating the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and then boolean indexing to change values as:

```
arr = np.arange(0,255)
mask = np.isin(arr,[0,1,3,16,17,18])

arr[mask]+=1
arr[~mask]=0
```

Or use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) as:

```
arr = np.where(np.isin(arr,[0,1,3,16,17,18]),arr+1,0)
```

---

```
arr
array([ 1,  2,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17,
       18, 19,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

Comment: That's just marvelous! I was converting and writing the arrays to disk like 50 arrays per seconds using traditional for loop. Now its more like 500 per seconds or more!

Comment: @Tahlil Numpy array methods are always fast. We need to know how to use it and where to use it properly.